# Exercise on a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Prove the following inequality:

$$\sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}< \frac{1}{m*m!} \forall m\in \mathbb{N^+}$$

My strategy of attack was to set up an inequality like $\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}< \frac{n-m}{m!}$ but the right-end side obviously tends to infinity, thus rendering the inequality useless. I tried to set up another inequality with something like $\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}$ but got nowhere. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a geometric series bound:
$$\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty\frac1{k!}<\frac1{(m+1)!}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(m+1)^k}=\frac1{(m+1)!}\cdot\frac1{1-\frac1{m+1}}=\frac1{(m+1)!}\cdot\frac{m+1}{m}=\frac1{m\cdot m!}$$

Comment: Nice! I hadn't thought of that! Just to clarify, how did the idea come to you?

Comment: @GennaroMarcoDevincenzis Well, the series decreases very rapidly, more than a geometric series. So why not use that fact?